# Unable to connect blob container using Python runbook

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

i am trying to connect & list the blob container using python runbook , it gives below error

**Error:**
Failed

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Temp\o54f0ym2.hp4\64f6d97c-4b5b-4ab5-80b2-e9425a2f829e", line 5, in     for blob in blob_list:  File "C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 128, in **next**    return next(self._page_iterator)  File "C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\core\paging.py", line 76, in **next**    self._response = self._get_next(self.continuation_token)  File "C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_list_blobs_helper.py", line 100, in _get_next_cb    process_storage_error(error)  File "C:\WPy64-3800\python-3.8.0.amd64\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob_shared\response_handlers.py", line 185, in process_storage_error    exec("raise error from None")   # pylint: disable=exec-used # nosec  File "", line 1, in azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.RequestId:78fa857f-001e-0057-5cbb-f2616a000000Time:2022-11-07T15:15:39.7021443ZErrorCode:AuthorizationFailureContent: `AuthorizationFailure`This request is not authorized to perform this operation.RequestId:78fa857f-001e-0057-5cbb-f2616a000000Time:2022-11-07T15:15:39.7021443Z

**i am using below code :**

```
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="", container_name="")
blob_list = container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name + '\n')
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the similar error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the **required permissions** are not granted to perform the action.

I created an **Azure Storage container** and uploaded test blob:

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to generate the **`connection string`** like below:

[image]

I am able to get the list of **blobs inside the container successfully** when I passed the `connection string` with the **required permissions** like below:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient
container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="", container_name="")
blob_list = container.list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print(blob.name + '\n')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Rukmini , i created a new storage container and it worked for me